# aws sdk sqs neither sending message or showing errors but stuck forever

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to use aws sdk to test [goaws](https://github.com/p4tin/goaws) but my following program just hangs forever. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint('http://localhost:4100')
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'}, {endpoint});

// Create an SQS service object
var sqs =  new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});

var params = {
    DelaySeconds: 10,
    MessageAttributes: {
        "Name": {
            DataType: "String",
            StringValue: "AAAA"
        },
        "SurName": {
            DataType: "String",
            StringValue: "BBBB"
        }
    },
    MessageBody: "whats up",
    QueueUrl: "http://us-east-1.goaws.com:4100/100010001000/local-queue1"
};

sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Success", data.MessageId);
    }
});
```

The sqs queue URL I tried testing with AWS cli and it does work. So there is something wrong in program which I don't understand.

```
aws sqs send-message --region us-east-1 --endpoint-url http://localhost:4100 --queue-url http://us-east-1.goaws.com:4100/100010001000/local-queue1 --message-body "Hello from Amazon SQS."
```

```json
{
  "MD5OfMessageBody": "c5dba0dd8f89fe763f66cbddb9c37cb7",
  "MD5OfMessageAttributes": "",
  "MessageId": "f5a8ce0d-983f-4fb5-b517-153d2c56c08b",
  "SequenceNumber": ""
}
```

Comment: Are you using a host file or some local dns resolution for goaws.com? I would expect your queue url to be localhost:4100. I haven't used this, but that jumps out at me.

Comment: Also, the application should be doing some info level logging with logrus, so if goaws is receiving a request it should do some logging. That may help indicate where your code halted.

Comment: I'm running goaws in docker container.  In the logs, there is no message arriving in the queue which explains the fact that above prog is not sending  any msg to sqs.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect the `endpiont` is not updated as you expect, so it may be hanging trying to reach the default api endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how your `config` update will work. First, I don't think endpoint is an attribute on the [global Config object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html). Also, it isn't set as an attribute in the dictionary, which should both the in the object that is the first argument. Next, I think you `QueueUrl` should be http://localhost:4100/100010001000/local-queue1. I believe that `endpoint` should be configured in the constructor for the [SQS resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#endpoint-property).

Here is some updated code that I have not tested, but I think will work.

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint('http://localhost:4100')
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

// Create an SQS service object
var sqs =  new AWS.SQS({
    apiVersion: '2012-11-05',
    endpoint: endpoint
});

var params = {
    DelaySeconds: 10,
    MessageAttributes: {
        "Name": {
            DataType: "String",
            StringValue: "AAAA"
        },
        "SurName": {
            DataType: "String",
            StringValue: "BBBB"
        }
    },
    MessageBody: "whats up",
    QueueUrl: "http://localhost:4100/100010001000/local-queue1"
};

sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Success", data.MessageId);
    }
});
```

In addition, I think the logs coming from goaws would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works.  The only thing , I dont understand that why QueueUrl should be "http://localhost:4100/100010001000/local-queue1".  Because AWS CLI was able to  respond QueueUrl: "http://us-east-1.goaws.com:4100/100010001000/local-queue1" without making any changes in dns etc.

Comment: @NewGuy I don't know without digging through the code, but I imagine they are just using the host as configured in the application, and essentially ignoring the url here; just using the path given. [Here for example](https://github.com/p4tin/goaws/blob/ba73e9b3195a592346488cab2dcaf61807605184/app/conf/config.go#L85) could have something to do with it, where they replace the url part with the configured host value. I really don't know, but that is a guess.